# El servidor Apache no se inicia en MAMP

Tags: apache

Me salta este aviso indicando que los puertos están ocupados y no sé el por que. necesito usar esos puertos. Intente cambiándolos y si se inicia el servidor APACHE pero necesito exactamente esos puertos. por favor ayuda.[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Lo más probable es que tengas algún proyecto ejecutándose en el puerto 80. Podrías dar más detalles del escenario, cosas como las que has estado realizando. Entre más detalles, mayor chance de obtener una buena respuesta. Saludos

Comment: Lo unico nuevo que estuve realizando fue instalar Postgres. y al parecer eso afecto todo.

Comment: Imposible. Postgresql se ejecuta en el puerto 5432.

Comment: Entonces debe tocar algo más para que esto pasara. muchas gracias por la respuesta.

Comment: Si la respuesta te solucionó tu problema, márcala como aceptada, le ayudarás al sitio a mantener la buena salud, efecto de % de preguntas resueltas. Saludos :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La solución es ejecutar este código.

```
sudo apachectl stop
```

y listo, se libera el puerto 80.

Comment: Entonces, tenías instalado el Apache, y tiene bastante sentido dado que el MAMP/WAMP/XAMP levantan otro apache en el mismo puerto. Saludos

Answer (score 0):

3 cosas para hacer: Identificar, entender y eliminar el proceso.

Identificar el proceso que tiene usando el puerto 80, el comando es el siguiente:

```
netstat -anvp tcp | awk 'NR<3 || /LISTEN/'
```

Este comando te dará un resultado como el siguiente:

```
Active Internet connections (including servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q  Local Address          Foreign Address        (state)     rhiwat shiwat    pid   epid  state    options
tcp46      0      0  *.62981                *.*                    LISTEN      131072 131072  34548      0 0x0100 0x00000006
…
```

Ahora que tienes la lista de **p**rocesos con su respectivo **id**, el famoso "PID", busca aquel proceso que esté usando el puerto 80 y anota el número del pid.

Si deseas ver todos los procesos, ejecuta este comando:

```
ps -ax
```

Finalmente, ahora que ya sabes cuál es el proceso, toca darle de baja con este comando:

```
kill <aqui va el numero del pid>
```

Por ejemplo:

```
kill 7896
```

Referencias:

- https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/117648
- https://www.chriswrites.com/how-to-view-and-kill-processes-using-the-terminal-in-mac-os-x/

Comment: Lo hice y me dio esta respuesta: 'kill: kill 12527 failed: operation not permitted'

Comment: Ese es el PID que esta usando el puerto 80

Comment: @Chelexwe error de permisos, coloca `sudo` antes de los comandos

Comment: Ahora si detiene el PID pero se inicia otro al instante manteniendo ocupado el puerto 80.

Comment: Vas a tener que editar la pregunta, colocar los nuevos datos que tienes. Es fijo que tienes un servicio ejecutándose constantemente en ese puerto.

Comment: ok. cerrare esta pregunta y abriré otra con la nueva información. muchas gracias por la ayuda.

Comment: vale, espero te vaya excelente :D